# A way to increase all set ranges or appear closer

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, ranged-attack

There are many set ranges in 3.5, point blank shot, skrimish, sneak attack etc. Either you go for each individually. Snipers shot, crossbow sniper etc. 
Is there a way to increase all static range limitations or performing a ranged attack and the arrow acting as if it was closer than you currently are. Eg: You're 35 feet away, but you're counted as being 10 feet closer to the enemy than you are, or the enemy is treated as being 10 feet closer to you.

This is a 3.5 game, all 1st party resources are allowed and any resource that can do this will be appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, you're looking for ways to increase the range at which a feat that grants a +1 bonus on attack rolls and a +1 bonus on damage rolls can be used? Is this for a *really* low-powered campaign or are there shenanigans involved? Also, what kind of resources are you willing to spend to do this?

Comment: Related, but no good for ranged weapons (except via AoO Snap Shot weirdness): [*Gloves of the Shortened Path*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gloves-of-the-shortened-path)

Comment: *Making enemies appear closer* is unusual.  Can you explain—either in comments or in the question—the house rules? I'm aware of a few things that extend the distance at which sneak attacks can be made, for instance, but it may take third-party material to extend the range of Point Blank Shot specifically. (I think, like, a *Spycraft* feat does that.) However, *What feats, special abilities, and magic items can I use to take advantage of this house rule?* is a legit question if the house rule is A) small and B) detailed. I mean, as phrased, a frame challenge would suggest instead free movement.

Comment: Aha! Okay, so this is a *theoretical* build, not an actual problem in a real campaign. That *should* still be okay—you're totally allowed to ask questions in anticipation of problems you may encounter later. Futureproofing your PC is a solid ask. As is, this *can* be answered, but, really, I'd still like to know what you're trying to do with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Archers' Standard** (price: 4000 gp, source: Forge of War (Eberron))

> Any allied archer who shoots an arrow or a bolt while under the effect of this standard [it affects your whole party] can ignore the first range increment. Thus, the attack does not start taking penalties until three range increments, rather than two, and it can travel as far as eleven range increments, rather than the normal maximum of ten.

It's unclear whether you're effectively 1 range increment closer for all purposes related to ranged attacks, or if it's only for purposes that are normally phrased in terms of range increments. But the generous interpretation does what you ask.

(You probably want to mount the standard on a backpack frame (price: 5gp, source: MIC), which lets you wear it as a shoulder-slot item. The other option is to mount it on a pole-arm, which is not ideal for an archer who's planning to stay away from melee and thus too far from your glaive-wielding friend to benefit from the AOE.)

---

**Sharn** race (source: Anauroch the Empire of Shade, or Monsters of Faerun)

Sharns have a whole bunch of unique abilities, one of which is that you can create small mobile one-way portals for you to attack through. The far ends of portals can roam up to 100 feet from you, thus effectively granting +100 feet range to all of your abilities.

caveat: 4RHD+5LA. Which can be worth it, but only if you're exploiting all of the racial abilities, not just the portals.